# simple C++ program to calculate number of instances of a substring

Tags: c++, string

can someone point out the error in the following code . I am using a naive approach of comparing both strings character by charcter and updating variable 'u' then comparing it with length of substring . If this is true then variable 'c' is updated by one unit.

Program in C++ :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char s[50],a[20];
cin.getline(s,50);
cin.getline(a,20);
//int l=strlen(s);
int p=strlen(a);
int i,c=0,j,u=0,k;
for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
{
       if(a[i]='\0')

       {break;} 

       if(s[i]==a[0])
         {
            for(j=i,k=0;a[k]!='\0';j++,k++)
                {
                  if(s[j]==a[k])
                    {
                      u++;
                      //continue;
                    }
                    //else
                    //break;
                 }
                   //cout<<endl<<u;                                                                          
           if(u==p)
             {
              c++;
             }
         }

     u=0;

   }
   cout<<endl<<"count "<<c;
   getch();
}
```

For any kind of input combination ,  I am getting output as 0.

Comment: You need to try to narrow down the problem more.  Step through it with a debugger, or have the program print output as it works, so you can get a better understanding of how it is working internally.

Comment: I recommend using `std::string` because it is safer and more readable.  The `std::string` will dynamically grow and you don't have to check for overflowing a character array or maintaining that pesky terminating '\0' character.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - also, `std::string` provides `std::string::find` which will do 90% of the work here.

Comment: The offending statement is this: `if(a[i]='\0')`. How about enabling all warnings on compile and treat warnings as errors?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this part:

```
if (a[i] = '\0')

{
  break;
}
```

First, you are using `=` instead of `==`, but that is not the entire problem. Either change `a[i]` to `s[i]`, or comment out the entire block. I don't see why it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

My tip and my coding convention to avoid your bug that you use `=` instead of `==` in:

```
if(a[i]='\0')
```

is to put the rvalue in the left side of the operand and the lvalue in the right side, like this:

```
if ('\0' == a[i])
```

this convention will avoid bugs like that(you will get a compilation error):

```
if ('\0' = a[i])
```

this code will generate a compilation error:

```
Error   C2106   '=': left operand must be l-value
```